# How do I reference host element in CSS of an Angular2 component?

Tags: css, typescript, angular

I have a component in Angular2 and I want to set the padding on the host element.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 'Hello world'
    styles: ['my-app {padding: 10px}']
})
```

in browser, my style looks like this:

```
my-app[_ngcontent-icu-3] {padding: 10px;}
```

while my host element looks like this:

```
<my-app _ngcontent-icu-1="" _nghost-icu-3="">
    <div class="content" _ngcontent-icu-3=""></div>
</my-app>
```

As I understand it, Angular2 adds these `_ng` attributes so CSS references specific components.

But how do I reference the host element from the CSS defined inside the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
styles: [':host {padding: 10px}']
```

or

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 'Hello world'
    host: {'[style.padding.px]': '"10"'}
})
```

The added `_ng...` classes are for emulating scoped styles (default `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`) similar to what shadow DOM does.

Comment: The first one is what I was looking for. I can use that in the CSS file as well.